# Linkedin post containing specific link was not published

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to create a post with a specific link attachment. Creation looks ok and it returns post id `urn:li:organization:33216775`. However, the post was not published.

Create Endpoint

`POST https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts`

Payload

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:organization:33216775",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    },
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": "looong link test 3",
                "attributes": []
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "ARTICLE",
            "media": [
                {
                    "originalUrl": "http://eye.sbc32.com/m2?r=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",
                    "status": "READY",
                    "description": {
                        "text": "description here"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "text": "title here"
                    },
                    "thumbnails": [
                        {
                            "url": "https://cdn-assets.socialbakers.com/t47P7mJbTeGC7diaS2AG_4000.jpg",
                            "width": 1920,
                            "height": 1440
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "id": "urn:li:share:6731878890031210496"
}
```

When I tried to retrieve the post I've got only exceptions below.

Retrieve endpoint

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A6731878890031210496`

Response

```
{
    "message": "com.linkedin.restli.server.RestLiServiceException [HTTP Status:403]: com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: com.linkedin.restli.server.RestLiServiceException [HTTP Status:403]: com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: Entity blocked by UCF. Filter error code: ucf.content.blocked. Exception is: com.linkedin.ucf.integration.BlockedEntityException",
    "status": 403
}
```

Retrieve endpoint

`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts/urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A6731878890031210496?viewContext=AUTHOR`

Response

```
{
    "message": "com.linkedin.restli.server.RestLiServiceException [HTTP Status:404]: com.linkedin.content.common.ResponseException: ",
    "status": 404
}
```

Comment: `BlockedEntityException` means this post was marked as spam.